# How can i track hot linkers ip address using php and htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am trying to track ip address of hotlinkers using php and htaccess.

.htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule images/(.+)\.(jpg|gif|png) images.php
```

images.php

```
?php 
    $ipAddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

    $statement=$db->prepare("INSERT INTO `ipaddress` (`ip` )
            VALUES (?)");
    $statement->execute(array($ipAddress));     

?>
```

Now a user request a image like this  www.domain.com/images/image.jpg it will redirect to images.php and track their ips. The problem i am facing here is inside my page  is not showing image (reason htaccess redirect it to images.php). How can i fix this problem?

[Here is the link of previous question regarding this issue:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11141496/how-can-i-track-hot-linkers-ip-address-using-php)

I am not expert in htaccess so need more explanations

Thanks

Comment: What do you want to do?  Do you want to log ip and show images or just log and exit for everybody and show images only without logging them for your own site?

Comment: I want to log IP and show images.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to log the IP and then serve the image anyway, then something like this might do:

.htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule images/(.+)\.(jpg|gif|png) images.php?image=$1.$2
```

images.php:

```
<?php 
    $ipAddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

    $statement=$db->prepare("INSERT INTO `ipaddress` (`ip` )
            VALUES (?)");
    $statement->execute(array($ipAddress));

    $ext = strtolower(end(explode('.', $_GET['image'])));

    if($ext == 'gif') {
        $type = "gif";
    }
    else if($ext == 'jpg') {
        $type = "jpeg";
    }
    else if($text == 'png') {
        $type = "png";
    }
    else {
        $type = "binary";
    }

    header("Content-type: image/$type");
    readfile("images/" . $_GET['image']);

?>
```

You may need to adjust paths here and there to make sure all files are correctly pointed to, both in `.htaccess` and in `images.php`.

Comment: $ext = lower(end(explode('.', $filename)));
here what is $filename  and lower() ?  strtolower()?

Comment: @Compiler oops, sorry, copy/paste issues.  I updated my answer.

Comment: i am trying images/image.png but all time else part is executing.i think something wrong at $_GET['image'] . In htaccess what is $1.$2?

Comment: @Compiler In .htaccess, you have two sets of parentheses. $1 corresponds to what's in the first set, $2 corresponds to what's in the second.  Try `print_r($_GET['image'])` in the beginning of your script to see whether you get the right image name.